# Arrays en PHP: Hacer explode de un explode

Tags: php, array

Me he quedado atascado en el código y a ver si podéis ayudarme.
Tengo un array donde guardo todos los productos comprados y sus características, por ejemplo:

echo $array;

Y mostraría esto: 'foto.jpg - juguete grande - azul - x3 - 10€,foto2.jpg - juguete mediano - verde - x2 - 5€'

Los he separado usando un explode(',' , $array); pero ahora me gustaría volver a separarlos en otro array que recoja cada característica de cada juguete.
Es decir, desde un string, sacar un array y luego un array bidimensional. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?
¡Gracias por adelantado!

Este el código que he escrito pero no funciona:

```
    $array_compra_html[] = explode(',',$array_compra);

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array_compra_html);$i++){
       $array_compra_doble[] = explode(' - ',$array_compra_html[$j]);
    }

    $compra_html = '<table>
                       <tr>
                          <td>Foto</td>
                          <td>Producto</td>
                          <td>Color</td>
                          <td>Cantidad</td>
                          <td>Precio unidad</td>
                       </tr>';

    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($array_compra_doble);$j++){
       $compra_html .= '<tr><td>'.$array_compra_doble[$i].'</td>
                            <td>'.$array_compra_doble[$i].'</td>
                            <td>'.$array_compra_doble[$i].'</td>
                            <td>'.$array_compra_doble[$i].'</td>
                            <td>'.$array_compra_doble[$i].'</td>
                        </tr>';
     }

   $compra_html .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu $array_compra tiene un index se mira de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenemos que quitar el `[0]` que está al inicio de tu array, tú le haces un `sizeof(array_compra_html)` a tu array y eso siempre te retorna un 1 entonces en tus for solo recorres la primera posición, para eso utilizaremos un foreach de esta forma:

```
$array_compra_doble = array();
    foreach ($array_compra_html[0] as $html) {
        array_push($array_compra_doble, explode(' - ',$html));
    }
```

Entonces aqui recorremos el array `$array_compra_html` y de una vez le pasamos a tu `array_compra_doble` los valores en un nuevo array que se vera de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

teniendo el `$array_compra_doble;` de esta forma solo basta con recorrer los valores para mostrarlos en tu tabla:

```
$compra_html = '<table>
                       <tr>
                          <td>Foto</td>
                          <td>Producto</td>
                          <td>Color</td>
                          <td>Cantidad</td>
                          <td>Precio unidad</td>
                       </tr>';
    
    foreach ($array_compra_doble as $value) {
        $compra_html .= '<tr><td>'.$value[0].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[2].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[3].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[4].'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
```

De esta forma te evitas poner tantas posiciones y en este caso si te mostrará todos los datos que agregues a tu variable `$array_compra`

**Código completo:**

```
 $array_compra = 'foto.jpg - juguete grande - azul - x3 - 10€,foto2.jpg - juguete mediano - verde - x2 - 5€';
    $array_compra_html[] = explode(',',$array_compra);
    
    $array_compra_doble = array();
    foreach ($array_compra_html[0] as $html) {
        array_push($array_compra_doble, explode(' - ',$html));
    }

    $compra_html = '<table>
                       <tr>
                          <td>Foto</td>
                          <td>Producto</td>
                          <td>Color</td>
                          <td>Cantidad</td>
                          <td>Precio unidad</td>
                       </tr>';
    
    foreach ($array_compra_doble as $value) {
        $compra_html .= '<tr><td>'.$value[0].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[2].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[3].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[4].'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
    
   $compra_html .= '</table>';
   echo $compra_html;
```

**Imagen del resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota: El código que puse antes tenia un error solo te mostraba 1 posición de la forma como te comento ahora si podrás mostrar todos los que desees siempre que los agregues en tu variable de `$array_compras`**

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias @José Vásquez! Gracias por tu tiempo probándolo y explicándomelo y ¡me lo has arreglado! ¡Eres un crack! ¡Gracias!

Comment: @KaixoGuti Edite el código tenía un error, espero lo cambies en tu codigo y te muestre todos los datos.

Comment: Cuando me diste la idea de cómo hacerlo ya cambié algunas cosas para ajustarlo a mi página web. Gracias @JoséVásquez ten un buen fin de semana!